# Changing image tag in OpenShift Deployment with CLI

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

is there a set of commands to change the docker image name/tag in an existing deployment in a project in an OpenShift cluster?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `oc set image` command to change the image for a container in an existing Deployment / DeploymentConfig:

```
oc set image dc/myapp mycontainer=nginx:1.9.1
```

Try `oc set image --help` for some examples.